# Springboot release connection

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have one async method that read one csv file and save in each row my postgresql.  so if my user start the process and go to the list of records(findAll() in my repository), all registers in cvs only show after my method finish to process all. I think that is because springboot only release my connection after the return of that method. I already try to use myRepo.flush() but withou success.

It`s possible to release every register after save? tks

```
@Asyng
public void myMethod(List<MyRecordCsv> files){

for(MyRecordCsv record: files){
   myRepo.save(record);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create new save method like:

`@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public void createMyRecorCsv(final MyRecordCsv myRecordCsv) {
    myRepo.save(myRecordCsv);
}`

Then call in the loop for each record.